# Laravel Polymorphic Relation, create relation for a morphOne

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm stuck with Polymorphic relations binding in Laravel (4). Modelnames are made up to make it more clear.

```
<?php

class Car extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['license_plate'];

    public function carable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Parkinglot extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['in_shadow'];

    public function carable()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Car', 'carable');
    }
}

class Garagebox extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['can_lock'];

    public function carable()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Car', 'carable');
    }
}
```

One Car can be stored in a Parkinglot Or a Garagebox. The ParkingLots and Garagebox can be created unlimited.

I have a html-Table, where all Parkingslots and Garageboxes are listed. If there is no Car stored in/on it, you can store One Car.

What I want is to make a MANAGE-button for each row. If there is a an existing Polymorphic relation, it finds that Car and you can edit it (that works already), but when there is no relation - so no Car attached - I want to save the Car Inside the row that was edited.

So I want a way to fill the `carable_id` and `carable_type` for the `Car::create();`, but how to achieve such a thing?

The [Model-class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L548) has functions like `firstOrCreate()` and `FirstOrNew()`, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? The Parkinglots/Garageboxes don't have to have a Car inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firstOrNew` for this. `firstOrNew` doesn't save the new model, it just gives you back a model ready to be saved.

```
$car = Car::firstOrNew([
    'make' => 'BMW', 
    'model' => '123d', 
    'registration' => 'YK10HMC'
]);
```

Then you can check if the model is new or not and branch from that.

```
if ($car->exists)
{
    // It was retrieved from DB as an existing car
} 
else
{
    // It is a new model and hasn't been saved yet
}
```

To save the car to a lot or garage, a lot in this case:

```
$storage = ParkingLot::find(1);

$storage->carable()->save($car);
```

Now the car has a `carable_type` of `ParkingLot` and a `carable_id` of 1.